# Chrome 81 NotAllowedError when accessing microphone

Tags: google-chrome, microphone, getusermedia, navigator

Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 (Current release) fails when trying to access to microphone using navigator.mediadevices.getUserMedia(). Default pop up to allow microphone is never shown on screen. Someone with the same issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at [chrome://settings/content/microphone](http://Look%20at%20chrome://settings/content/microphone%20and%20chrome://settings/content/camera%20.%20You%20may%20have%20denied%20access%20already,%20in%20which%20case%20Chrom(ium)%20won't%20prompt%20again.%20You%20can%20also%20click%20on%20the%20https%20lock%20in%20the%20Location%20bar.%20Also,%20you%20MUST%20serve%20pages%20using%20gUM%20from%20https%20servers.%20Because%20cybercreeps.) and [chrome://settings/content/camera](http://Look%20at%20chrome://settings/content/microphone%20and%20chrome://settings/content/camera%20.%20You%20may%20have%20denied%20access%20already,%20in%20which%20case%20Chrom(ium)%20won't%20prompt%20again.%20You%20can%20also%20click%20on%20the%20https%20lock%20in%20the%20Location%20bar.%20Also,%20you%20MUST%20serve%20pages%20using%20gUM%20from%20https%20servers.%20Because%20cybercreeps.) . You may have denied access already, in which case Chrom(ium) won't prompt again. You can also click on the https lock in the Location bar.

Also, you MUST serve pages using gUM from https servers. Because cybercreeps. If your pages  / javascript can be static, both github and gitlab offer ways to serve them without having to  muck around with certificates and servers.